# Floodfill algorithm takes a few seconds

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am programming a very basic paint application.

My app have an image and when I touch in any place this place fill with a color.

I use a flood fill algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), specifically the second approach of `Alternative implementations` section.

I use a pixmap in order to update the texture.

This works fine on my computer, the problem is when execute the app on my android (motorola moto G with 720p resolution, Android 4.4), the algorithm takes a few second and I don't like that, I want that this process takes less time. So, the problem is that with a high resolution (or with a big portion to fill) the algorithm takes a few seconds.

One thing I did is check every 5 pixel instead 1 pixel, But I want to know if there is other optimization.

I know that there are app that do this (like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coloring.toddlers&hl=en). Anybody can tell me any advice?

Thanks.

Edit: Update the question with some code (I have removed empty method from interfaces). Is probably that there are unused variables. This is the version that check every pixel.

My floodfill algorithm

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.*;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import es.angelluis..Actors.BackgroundActor;
import es.angelluis..Actors.ImageActor;
import es.angelluis..util.Pixel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Images implements Screen, InputProcessor {

    private Stage stage;
    private ImageActor img = new ImageActor();
    private AssetManager manager;
    private Texture texture = null;

    public Images(){
        manager = new AssetManager();
        stage = new Stage();
        manager.load("dibujo1.png",Texture.class);
        stage.addActor(img);
        InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
        im.addProcessor(this);
        im.addProcessor(stage);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);


    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        if (manager.update()){
            if (!img.loaded){
                texture = manager.get("dibujo1.png", Texture.class);
                int x = (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-texture.getWidth())/2;
                int y = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-texture.getHeight())/2;
                img.load(texture, x,y, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
                texture.getTextureData().prepare();
                pix = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
            }
            stage.draw();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        int colorSelected = Color.rgba8888(Color.RED);

        if (screenX < img.getX() || screenX > img.getX() + img.getWidth() || screenY < img.getY() || screenY > img.getY() + img.getHeight()){
            return false;
        }

        //Get Texture to update.
        Pixmap source = img.getPixmap();
        // Obtenemos las coordenadas locales a la textura.
        screenX = screenX - (int)img.getX();
        screenY = screenY - (int)img.getY();
        // Get Color.
        int colorInicial = source.getPixel(screenX, screenY);



        // If color is the same we will exit.
        if (colorInicial == colorSelected){
            return false;
        }

        ArrayList<Pixel> pixels = new ArrayList<Pixel>();
        int colorPixel = source.getPixel(screenX, screenY);

        if (colorPixel == colorInicial){
            // Store the initial pixel in pixels linked list.
            pixels.add(new Pixel(screenX, screenY));
            while(!pixels.isEmpty()){
                Pixel p = pixels.get(0);
                source.setColor(Color.RED);
                source.drawPixel(p.getX(), p.getY());
                pixels.remove(0);
                // Now get all pixel that I should be update in this y coords. So get west and east.
                ArrayList<Pixel> line = new ArrayList<Pixel>();
                int w = p.getX()-1;
                colorPixel = source.getPixel(w, p.getY());
                while (colorPixel == colorInicial && w != 0){
                    line.add(new Pixel(w, p.getY()));
                    w--;
                    colorPixel = source.getPixel(w, p.getY());
                }
                int e = p.getX() + 1;
                colorPixel = source.getPixel(e, p.getY());
                while (colorPixel == colorInicial && e != img.getWidth()){
                    line.add(new Pixel(e, p.getY()));
                    e++;
                    colorPixel = source.getPixel(e, p.getY());
                }

                // Draw the line that I store before.
                while (!line.isEmpty()){
                    Pixel linePixel = line.get(0);
                    line.remove(0);
                    source.setColor(Color.RED);
                    source.drawPixel(linePixel.getX(), linePixel.getY());

                    // I check  the north pixel and store it if they should be updated
                    colorPixel = source.getPixel(linePixel.getX(), linePixel.getY()+1);
                    if (colorPixel == colorInicial){

                        pixels.add(new Pixel(linePixel.getX(), linePixel.getY()+1));
                    }
                    // I check the south pixel and store it if they should be updated
                    colorPixel = source.getPixel(linePixel.getX(), linePixel.getY()-1);
                    if (colorPixel == colorInicial){
                        //System.out.println("Entramos en sur");

                        pixels.add(new Pixel(linePixel.getX(), linePixel.getY()-1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        img.setTexture(new Texture(source));
        return false;
    }
}
```

ImageActor

```
package es.angelluis..Actors;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;

public class ImageActor extends Actor{

    private Texture img;
    public boolean loaded = false;
    private int x,y,width,height;

    public void load(Texture img, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.img = img;
        loaded = true;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setTexture(Texture img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    public Pixmap getPixmap(){
        if (!img.getTextureData().isPrepared()){
            img.getTextureData().prepare();
        }
        return img.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.draw(img, x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code.  How are you setting pixels?  Modern hardware is not designed to set pixels one by one.  You need to build the complete filled image in a bitmap and copy it to the graphics device.

Comment: I updated my question with some code

Answer (score 0):

A common error when doing such things is that you are trying to update the screen bitmap, which slows the process down by a lot, because the application is trying to update the screen meanwhile.
The solution for this problem is copying the screen into a bitmap, doing your fill algorithm on that bitmap, and copying the result back to the screen when you are finished.
If you provide some code, we can check your approach.